# Mastodon API remote boost what's the :id?

Tags: mastodon

I would like to write a Chrome extension which makes boosting toots on another instance more seamless.

I am looking at https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/statuses/#boost

It says `POST /api/v1/statuses/:id/reblog`

About `:id` it says "The ID of the Status in the database."

How do I find this for a remote toot?

Comment: How are you getting the status(es) that you want to boost?

Comment: I would like to write a Chrome extension which makes boosting from another server much smoother. In short: I have an URL from another Mastodon instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [search API](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/search/) to locate the status based on its URL, like this:

```
GET endpoint/api/v2/search?resolve=true&q=https://endpoint/status_url
```

If the URL is valid, you will have an item inside `statuses` object and you can pick its `id` from there. Path would be `statuses[0].id`, but ensure `statuses` length is greater than 0 to confirm the URL is valid.

Use that ID to make the request to the boost method.